# Chrome - Difference between event time in devtools timeline and performance timing API

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, navigation-timing-api

I'm trying to get for example `loadEventEnd` time in console. You can do it by [performance timing 2 API](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/) or [performance timing API](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/).
I get the same results by doing this calculations:

```
performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].loadEventEnd
// 483.915
chrome.loadTimes().finishLoadTime * 1000 - chrome.loadTimes().startLoadTime * 1000 
// 484
performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart
// 484
```

But in Timeline tab in devtools I get result **510 ms**.
Differences are shown in this picture:

[image]

This problem occurs on the others sites: in console I always get shorter times than in Timeline tab.
Can someone explain this difference? 
Which one time is real?

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason my installation of Chrome 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit) doesn't have Timeline tab, so I can't provide any actual research. However, my hunch is that the difference between console and Timeline is coming from a brief delay needed to boot up JavaScript for the new tab. In your example, the difference is 30ms - have you looked whether anything happens in Timeline tab around the 30ms mark?

Comment: @Dragomok You are right. At 26 ms in timeline appears `navigationStart` event. So if you subtract from `loadEventEnd` `navigationStart` you will end up with 484 ms. Problem was that timeline was recorded before `navigationStart` which is different for `navigation-timing-api`.

Comment: @Dragomok in version 58 timeline is now in Performance tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dragomok in comment suggest:

`navigation-timing-api` starts record on `navigationStart` event. Performance tab timeline starts records "some time" before `navigationStart` event, that's why `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].loadEventEnd` gives smaller value than `loadEventEnd` in timeline.

If you calculate timeline `loadEventEnd - navigationStart` you will get the same value as in `navigation-timing-api`.

Here is proof in pictures:
[image]

[image]